# How to execute an OS-X command line tool with arguments from a Xamarin Mac Application

Tags: xamarin, command-line

How can i execute the following shell command with args from c# in a Xamarin Mac Application running on OS-X?

```
rsync -avz foo:src/bar/ /data/tmp
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029218/run-bash-commands-from-mono-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a terminal command in Xamarin.Mac and read-in its output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751590/how-to-execute-a-terminal-command-in-xamarin-mac-and-read-in-its-output)